# SQL counting of newly created variable within the same resultset

Tags: sql, count

so I'm reading some information from an existing table and creating a new variable (wgtdiff) which is the difference of 2 of the variables in the original data table then putting them into groups because I wanted to know how much of the population have a difference of 0-5, 5-10, etc.... and what I wanted to get to is being able to show what percent of the population falls into which bucket (let's say 0-5 is consider one bucket) by strand. I found examples of count of the original table and tried and didn't work. Can I count a variable I just created? Here's what I have:

```
select heat_no as HeatNo, grade_id as Grade, strand_no as Strand,
       cast_seq as CastSeq, billet_weight as bli_billet_weight,
       plc_weight as bli_plc_weight, billet_date as bli_billet_date,
       round ((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2) as Wgtdiff_plc_aim,
       CASE WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) <= 5 THEN '0 to +/- 5'
            WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) between 5.01 and 10 THEN '+/- 5 to 10'
            WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) between 10.01 and 15 THEN '+/- 10 to 15'
            WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) between 15.01 and 20 THEN '+/- 15 to 20'
            Else 'Greater than +/- 20'
       END as CASE
from Billet_table
```

Comment: You cannot use column aliases in the same select where they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery:

```
select HeatNo, Grade, Strand, CastSeq, bli_billet_weight, bli_plc_weight, bli_billet_date,Wgtdiff_plc_aim
CASE WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) <= 5 THEN '0 to +/- 5'
    WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) <= 10 THEN '+/- 5 to 10'
    WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) <= 15 THEN '+/- 10 to 15'
    WHEN abs(round((bli_plc_weight - bli_billet_weight),2)) <= 20 THEN '+/- 15 to 20'
    Else 'Greater than +/- 20'
END as CASE
from (select heat_no as HeatNo, grade_id as Grade, strand_no as Strand,
           cast_seq as CastSeq, billet_weight as bli_billet_weight,
           plc_weight as bli_plc_weight, billet_date as bli_billet_date,
           round ((plc_weight - billet_weight),2) as Wgtdiff_plc_aim
     from Billet_table) temp
```

Comment: I changed the `... THEN ` parts of the `CASE` statement, these `between 5.01 and 10`conditions can be dangerous. [So you probably don't need to use `round` anymore.]

Comment: Hi Giorgos, for the correction - I think replacing between with <= makes it a lot cleaner. So now what I have is a new column called CASE with the assigned text values such as '0 to +/-5'. When you say using a subquery, does it mean that I have to first do what I've already done and make that into a new table say TABLENEW which includes the field CASE then select from TABLENEW and create a new field to keep count of how many '0 to 5', '5 to 10'? My end goal here is to be able to get something like a pareto chart for a report to see what % of the product can be cut accurately. THANKS

Comment: No, the subquery is the expression between the parentheses in `select ... END as CASE from (<this is the subquery>) temp`. As I understand it, the query I wrote should cover you.